If $f(x), g(x) \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$, and $v_{p}(g(\alpha)) = t ~\forall \alpha \in Z(f)$. Can $g(x) = p^t h(x)$?
Let $f(x), g(x) \in \Bbb{Z}_{p}[x]$(where $\Bbb Z_p$ is the set of all $p$-adic integers). Also, assume that $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ and $g(x)$ be any polynomial of degree $m \geq n$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$. Let $v_p(\alpha) = \dfrac{u}{v}$, where $u,v \in \Bbb{N}$ and $\gcd(u,v) = 1$. We can write $\alpha = \pi^u \beta$, where $\pi$ is a root of $x^{v} = p$ in $R := \mathbb Z_p[x]/\langle x^v - p\rangle$. Also, it is very clear that $v_p(\beta) = 0$


If $g(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{m}g_{j}x^j$ and $v_{p}(g(\alpha)) = t$($t \in \Bbb{Q}$) for all root $\alpha \in Z(f) = \{x: f(x) = 0\}$. Then can we define a function let's say $h(x)$, which satisfies the following property $g(\pi^ux) = p^th(x)$, where $v_p(h(\beta)) = 0$ and $h(x) \in R[x]$?


Here one thing is clear if it is true then $g(\pi^v\beta) = p^th(\beta)$, that is $g(\alpha) = p^th(\beta)$, and as $v_p(g(\alpha)) = t$, hence $v_p(h(\beta)) = 0$ and $h(x) \in R[x]$.
Edit 1: This is a follow-up question to this question.
Edit 2: I have an idea that may work if $f(x)$ has all distinct roots. As any root of $f$ has the same valuation. If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n$ are $n$ distinct roots of $f$, then we can write it as $\pi^v\beta_1, \pi^v\beta_2, \cdots, \pi^v\beta_n$ are $n$ distinct roots of $f$.
Define $h(\beta) := \dfrac{g(\pi^v\beta)}{p^t} \in R$ for all distinct $\beta$. Now by Lagrange interpolation we can define a polynomial $h(x) \in R[x]$, which passes through the points $(\beta,\dfrac{g(\pi^v\beta)}{p^t})$.
But I don't know the proof for other possibilities.

Also, sure there is "a function" $h$, just define it as $h(x) :=g(\pi^v x)/p^t$. If you want that function to be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$ again, then I think my counterexample to the previous question again gives a counterexample to this.

I don't want that $h(x) \in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ I want $h(x) \in R[x]$, where in the question I define $R$.

Here $v _p(\alpha) \in \Bbb{Q} \setminus {0}$

In my counterexample, $v=1$ hence $R=\mathbb Z_p$ and it still is a counterexample. As to your edit, to find a polynomial that passes through $n$ given points is nice, but of course will not say anything about any other points. And by the way not even that polynomial is guaranteed to have coefficients of high enough valuation.

But in that example $\alpha = 1$, so for $p= 2$, $v_p(\alpha) = \dfrac{0}{1}$, so obviously $v = 1$ but $u = 0$, but I am not considering that case as I already assume $v_p(\alpha) \neq 0$. Because in that case, your counterexample works perfectly. But now I am curious about in which case we can surely say this holds.

@TorstenSchoeneberg, I may not have understood your comment clearly. If all the roots are distinct for that case, can't we say a polynomial $h(x) \in R[x]$ satisfies the condition?

Also for $h$, I am interested if $v_p(h(\beta)) = 0$ for all $\beta$ such that $\alpha = \pi^v \beta \in Z(f)$. Here we are not interested in the other points, right?

Well then take $p=\alpha=2$ and $g(x)=x+2$. Then $u=v=1, t=2$, but $g(px)/p^t = \frac12 x +\frac12$, the unique candidate for $h$, does not have coefficients in $R=\mathbb Z_p$. By the way, question title and body don't match, and also $f$ is completely irrelevant except for providing us with some set of $\alpha$'s.
